# How do avoid open redirection with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, security

What should be an alternate way for following code to avoid open redirection

```
var url = window.location.href;    
url = url.replace("abc.jsp","xyz.jsp"); 
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: what security issues are you trying to avoid?

Comment: open redirection. as i use window.location.href, assigning it to url will might end up for phishing attack

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
function redirect(url) {
  let $a = $('<a href="#"></a>');
  $a.attr('href', url);
  $a[0].click();
}

$(function(){
    //Use:
    redirect('https://www.google.com/');
});
```

Create a link dynamically and simulate a click on it.